# MacBook Pro not responding to power button

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, startup, power-management

My Mac wont start up even with full battery and charger plugged in... There is no sound, no screen or any disk movement.

The same thing also happened a few weeks back and when I took it to the repair guy; he fixed it in a matter of minutes.

He held down the power button for 10 seconds, removed the charger and did *something* else and the system started working but I don't exactly remember what he did.

**Can anyone tell me what those magic steps are?**

I am currently out of town and can’t take it there again.

Any help please?

Answer (score 7):

Maybe it was an [SMC reset](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3964):

> ### Resetting the SMC on portables with a battery you should not remove on your own
>
> Note: Portable computers that have a battery you should not remove on your own include MacBook Pro (Early 2009) and later, all models of MacBook Air, and MacBook (Late 2009).
>
> 1. Shut down the computer.
> 2. Plug in the MagSafe power adapter to a power source, connecting it to the Mac if its not already connected.
> 3. On the built-in keyboard, press the (left side) Shift-Control-Option keys and the power button at the same time.
> 4. Release all the keys and the power button at the same time.
> 5. Press the power button to turn on the computer.
> 6. Note: The LED on the MagSafe power adapter may change states or temporarily turn off when you reset the SMC.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what they did

1. Unplug the power cable.
2. Hold the power button for 20 sec.
3. When you reach 10 plug the power cable back in.
4. After the 20 seconds, it should power up fine.

Sadly, my Mac's battery doesn't work so every time I want to power it on I have to do the same thing every time.